# radiobutton styling in winForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, coding-style

Hey I was just wondering the techniques everyone uses to style radio buttons in winForms.  I find them very plain, and would like to add some color or different images for the controls.  The only way I can think of is to actually use a button that looks like a radiobutton, and set it to true or false.

Just wondering if there is a way I can do this, but still use the radio control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the [RadioButton MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.aspx).

Here you can see that you can, like many Controls :

- change the Button [Apparence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.appearance.aspx).
- change the Button [Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158232.aspx).
- change the Button [BackGroundImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimage.aspx).

There are many options to create your CustomRadioButton.

Comment: changing the appearance to a button, and adding my own background image works well, thanks!

Comment: dont forget to set AutoSize = false to resize.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two links which you can use to customize your controls

http://www.devexpress.com
http://www.dotnetskin.net